# Grails with Oracle thick OCI driver authenticate to Oracle with wrong user

Tags: oracle, security, grails, jdbc, grails-orm

I have set up authenticate Oracle using certificates stored in an Oracle wallet by having the following lines in

sqlnet.ora. sqlnet.ora is located in my Linux home directory.

```
 WALLET_LOCATION =
    (SOURCE =
      (METHOD = FILE)
      (METHOD_DATA =
        (DIRECTORY = my_wallet_location)
      )
     )

 SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

And set the username and password to "" in DataSource.groovy

```
 username=""
 password=""
```

However, after I started up my grails app, I found my app did os authentication which logged me into Oracle as ops$john as supposed to john and completely disregarded my wallet set up.

Please advise.

Update :

Here is the rest of the DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username=""
    password=""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@//myhost:myport/myinstance"
            properties {
                // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                maxActive = 50
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of your DataSource.groovy?

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: Try using a url with this format: jdbc:oracle:oci:/@alias where alias is the wallet alias in your  tnsnanems.ora file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a url with this `format: jdbc:oracle:oci:/@alias` where alias is the wallet alias in your `tnsnames.ora` file.

This option is documented in several places for example [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/WebLogicServer/entry/weblogic_database_use_of_oracle) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/JDBCA/oraclewallet.htm#JDBCA604). Most documentation is referencing the thin driver but it works the same way with the OCI driver. This [post](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_wallet_secure_external_password_file.htm) describes the complete process of creating and using a wallet with the OCI driver

Comment: It works. Is this documented any where ? Can you provide a link? Or you just guessed it?

Comment: It is documented in several places. I added links to the answer